# Distinguish abstract base class from implementation

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass, abc

Developing a metaclass that provides self-registration of subclasses (somewhat similar to [this idea](http://effbot.org/zone/metaclass-plugins.htm)), I came across the following problem:

Given a class that may be either an abstract base class or an implementation of one, how do I distinguish which it is?

Comment: err, you don't distinguish the two : that's what abstraction is for. If not, your architecture should be reviewed. If you really want to make the separation, you can always use the **__class__** variable

Comment: Define what makes a class abstract and check that condition. For example you might want to check that `SomeClass.method is not AbstractClass.method`, i.e. `SomeClass` has redefined the abstract method.

Comment: Well, the point is, I want to register them for deserialization and only deserialize those classes that inherit my abstract base class. However, it does not make a lot of sense to deserialize something with an abstract base class as a type. Therefore, I wanted to skip the registration of the base class itself.

Comment: @Bakuriu: this still depends on the particular abc you work with. Is there a more general way to do it? How does ABCMeta figure out, whether everything has been implemented?

Comment: Pretty simple: it provides an `abstractmethod` decorator that you **must** apply to the methods that are abstract. Then when the metaclass is called at class construction it can check whether there are methods that are `abstractmethod`s. It does this adding an `__isabstractmethod__` attribute to the methods. If any method has that attribute set to `True` then the class is abstract, otherwise it can be instantiated.

Comment: I see... I was not aware of the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute. That does answer my question. If it were an answer, I would accept it ;)